# How to make the char array the same size as the input (or can it be done using the string lib as opposed to C-style array strings)?

Tags: c++, c, string, arrays

So, I'm not really new to C++, but I rushed through all the tutorials in excitement, and now I'm going back and actually trying to apply my knowledge and build on it. I've been working on a small encryption algorithm; nothing special, just input, encrypt and output to the command prompt window.

The problem is, I create a char array of, say, 9 variables. I then use cin.getline(array,8) to get user input of up to 8 characters. It's all good if I enter exactly 8. But, if I enter less, then there are random characters on the end of the inputted word.

So, I was wondering if there's maybe a way to create the array the exact size of the characters entered? Or, even better, is there any way I could make an encryption algorithm using the C++ string library? I'm not sure how to change an individual character of a C++ string without converting it into a char array, so I'm pretty much back where I started.

I know this is probably a stupid question, but I've already ended up back at basics twice after rushing through everything that I didn't understand, so I really want to make sure I know everything this time around.

Any help is really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter Password: ";

    std::string password;
    std::cin >> password;

    for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); ++i)
    {
        // a std::string can be accessed like a c-style array
        std::cout << "password[" << i << "] = " << password[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to leave it the way you've got it; but make sure that when you use the characters in your array, you stop when you get to the terminating zero.  So your encryption algorithm (or whatever else you're writing) needs to check for zero each time it reads a character from the array.  This is a fairly standard way of dealing with character data in C or C++.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot :) But now for some reason, the front of the string is dropping off halfway through the algorithm. The output is here http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg694/scaled.php?server=694&filename=cusersuserdocumentsvisu.png&res=medium and the program is here http://pastebin.com/zfwL8xME. Any idea why that could happen?

Comment: Because if `i` is big enough, right-shifting `i` bits pushes everything away and turns your character to zero.  Then when you output it, the `<<` operator stops writing when it gets to a zero character.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about that :/ Well, I've replaced >> with + and it's all working great now. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `cin.gcount()` to obtain the actual number of characters read into your array.

see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/gcount/

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't I need to have already made the array to input the characters into? Although I could copy that to a new array, I guess.